# Material design theme not work in IE7 and IE8

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using meterial design angular theme in our application, but it is not supported in IE7 and IE8.

I am sharing the screen of console error.
[I8 console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RnIq.png)

Can anybody suggest me the best solution for this.

Comment: have you tried checking console for the errors?

Comment: Yes, There was lots of error are coming, as i have used multiple angular JS plugins.

Comment: You should probably check the [help], because the post is currently *very* hard to understand. Put yourself in our shoes: all we have to go on is your title and two lines of text...

Comment: following console errors are coming when i open the site in IE8. Link: goo.gl/lclmnL

Comment: @Satya have you seen the console error in the screen which i had shared.

Comment: Could you provide some more details? Edit the post to include a link to the theme that you're using, and the most important error messages you're getting.

Comment: The best solution is to not allow access to your site from deprecated browsers and to direct visitors using deprecated browsers to urls that will allow them to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Angular Material

> **Supported platforms:** Tested on IE 11+, Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Android 4.2+ and iOS 8+.

Check [this](http://angularjs.blogspot.co.uk/2015/12/angular-material-10-now-available.html) post for more details.